# Clean string to have only numbers c#

Tags: c#

I want to do have only the numbers from a string. I have tried this:

```
        string phoneNumber = txtPhoneNumber.Text;
        string cleanPhoneNumber = string.Empty;

        foreach (char c in phoneNumber)
        {
            if (c.Equals('0') || c.Equals('1') || c.Equals('2') || 
                c.Equals('3') || c.Equals('4') || c.Equals('5') ||
                c.Equals('6') || c.Equals('7') || c.Equals('8') || 
                c.Equals('9'))
                cleanPhoneNumber += Convert.ToString(c);
        }
```

The solution above worked, but i want to know if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: `string cleanPhoneNumber = string.Concat(phoneNumber.Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));`

Answer (score 3):

```
string b = string.Empty;
for (int i=0; i< a.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(a[i]))
        b += a[i];
}
```

Or use Regex

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
```

Comment: You could shorten that loop with a little bit of LINQ: `string b = string.Join("", a.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)));`.

Comment: `b += a[i]` isn't efficient. You're creating a new string each time.

Comment: @Sean - It'd be one hell of a phone number for the inefficiency to be significant.

Answer (score 3):

Since you, probable, want digits in `0..9` range only, not all *unicode* ones (which include *Persian*, *Indian* digits etc.), `char.IsDigit` and `\d` regular expression are not exact solutions.

**Linq:**

```
string cleanPhoneNumber = string.Concat(phoneNumber.Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));
```

**Regex:**

either *Sami*'s, *integer*'s codes or

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+", RegexOptions.ECMAScript ).Value;
```

which is *Krystian Borysewicz*'s solution with `ECMAScript` option to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

```
 string phoneNumber = txtPhoneNumber.Text;

// Get numbers only

 Regex numbersRegex = new Regex("[^0-9]");
 var cleanPhoneNumber = numbersRegex.Replace(phoneNumber, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to be efficient in terms on time then you should avoid using regex as the `Regex` class will need to parse your expression before it applies it to the phone number.

The code below avoid regex and keeps memory allocations to a minimum. It only allocates twice, once for a buffer to store the numbers and the once again at the end to create the string containing the valid numbers.

```
string Clean(string text)
{
    var validCharacters = new char[text.Length];
    var next = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = text[i];
        if(char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            validCharacters[next++] = c;
        }
    }

    return new string(validCharacters, 0, next);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using Linq:

```
string cleanPhoneNumber = new String(phoneNumber.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```